# what is the onSaveInstanceState equivalent in IOS?

Tags: android, ios

Is there an IOS analog for the methods `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` from Android?

Or does IOS just keep all of its `ViewControllers` alive for the duration of the application lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) section of the `UIViewController` documentation, and `UIViewController`'s [`restorationIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621499-restorationidentifier) property.